# Connect tkinter window with pyqt5 gui

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pyqt, pyqt5

How can I connect Tkinter window with pyqt5 Gui?

> like  pressing a push button in pyqt5 Gui and Tkinter window should  pop up

I have two tkinter window which I want to popup separately  after pressing different  pushbuttons for each
if I  press any button, both windows  popup together multiple times

like  pressing a push button in pyqt5 gui and tkinter window should  pop up

Comment: Don't. Using two GUI toolkits together is rarely possible, practically difficult, extremely discouraged, and almost always unnecessary, if not completely wrong. Either use Tk, or Qt.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to have one class using Tkinter and the other using PyQt5.

However, while this solution does work it leads to a reoccurring error, which does not affect the code itself. You will need to call the class via the PyQT5 code. Here is a solution below:

```
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *


from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
from tkinter.ttk import Notebook
from tkinter.ttk import Treeview
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter.font



class Widget2():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.gui(parent)

    def gui(self, parent):
        if parent == 0:
            self.w2 = Tk()
            self.w2.geometry('130x60')
        else:
            self.w2 = Frame(parent)
            self.w2.place(x = 0, y = 0, width = 130, height = 60)
        self.button1 = Button(self.w2, text = "Button", font = tkinter.font.Font(family = "Calibri", size = 9), cursor = "arrow", state = "normal")
        self.button1.place(x = 20, y = 20, width = 90, height = 22)

class Widget1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.gui()

    def gui(self):
        self.w1 = self
        self.w1.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.w1.setWindowTitle("")
        self.w1.resize(500, 450)
        self.w1.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
        self.w1.setToolTip("")
        self.button1 = QToolButton(self.w1)
        self.button1.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.button1.setText("Button")
        self.button1.move(9, 214)
        self.button1.resize(482, 22)
        self.button1.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
        self.button1.setToolTip("")
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.event)
        return self.w1

    def event(self):
        b = Widget2(0)
        b.w2.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    a = Widget1()
    a.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please listen to @musicamante . He is correct in saying it is bad to mix GUI toolkits together and if you can in the future just use one GUI toolkit.